# how can i update a blob data from a image in sqlight in xcode

Tags: xcode, ios4

how can i update image in sqlite

I have an image from imagePickerView and i want to save it in blob format in my sql how can that posibale my sorce code hear

```
NSString *item = str_Name;
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;


NSString *databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SLAMEBOOK" ofType:@"sql"];
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &SLAMEBOOK) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE SlammyDetail SET Name= \"%@\", BDate=\"%@\"  WHERE Name = \"%@\"", txt_Name.text ,lbl_date.text, item];

    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(SLAMEBOOK, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" 
                                                        message:@"REMINDER Updated" 
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    else 
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                                        message:@"Failed to add Task" 
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(SLAMEBOOK);

}

[txt_Name resignFirstResponder];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Comment: Get Solution Use FMDB for save

Comment: You are updating the database *within* the app bundle.  Bad idea.  You need to copy it to the Documents folder on first use.